# C# Sort files in directory by ordering by part in the name?

Tags: c#

I have files in directory like that
....

when i loading files:

```
FileInfo[] filelistIF = direcinfo.GetFiles("*.jpg");
```

> ```
> IMAGE-1-0853217IMG1.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853218IMG3.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853535IMG4.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853536IMG5.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853537IMG6.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853538IMG7.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853539IMG8.jpg 
> IMAGE-2-0853435IMG2.jpg 
> IMAGE-2-0853436IMG9.jpg 
> IMAGE-2-0853437IMG10.jpg
> IMAGE-2-0853438IMG11.jpg
> ```

I want sort file names  by 'IMG' like:

> ```
> IMAGE-1-0853217IMG1.jpg 
> IMAGE-2-0853435IMG2.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853218IMG3.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853535IMG4.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853536IMG5.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853537IMG6.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853538IMG7.jpg 
> IMAGE-1-0853539IMG8.jpg 
> IMAGE-2-0853436IMG9.jpg 
> IMAGE-2-0853437IMG10.jpg
> IMAGE-2-0853438IMG11.jpg
> ```

How to fix that? Please Help

Comment: Rather than readers guessing from the two lists, can you please be more explicit about the sort criteria.. Like I want to sort by characters x-y of the file name... or whatever criteria you have in mind.. My eyes are glazing over the list, not wanting to guess the sort criteria used.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for some code quick, and you don't care about its quality:

```
FileInfo[] filelistIF = direcinfo.GetFiles("*.jpg")
    .OrderBy(x =>
        int.Parse(x.Name.Substring(x.Name.IndexOf("IMG") + 3).Replace(".jpg", "")))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: You can probably get rid of the those two `Select()` parts and change it to this: `FileInfo[] filelistIF = direcinfo.GetFiles("*.jpg").OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Name.Substring(x.Name.IndexOf("IMG") + 3))).ToArray();` -- but of course with the multi-line formatting as in Dan's example (which I don't think I can do in a comment here...)